# React Multi Step Form Submit and Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

So I have a form inside a master page, where it will render different textbox, or radio box, or date picker, etc. On every click of next button and back button, it will either go to the next component or prev component, and save the whole form.

Pretend data model will look like this
{field: [{textbox1: texbox1value}, {datepicker1: datepicker1value}]

Given a pseudocode more or less like this.

ContainerPage.ts

```
<form>
   renderComponent(listOfComponent) // this will switch based on the link
   <button back>
   <button next>
</form>
```

Component1.ts

```
<input textbox>
```

Component2.ts

```
<input datepicker>
```

I was able to get it going to save, but wondering how do you validate the input if the button is on the parent component?

I'm following this site more or less but it does not have validation
https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/

I also saw some site develop it in such a way the form is on each component instead of the master page. but ended up using 1 form.

Answer (score 0):

Theres are some ways to handle that. My favorite way is to add a callback function to the form-component that will be called when the validation of the form is changed.
So you never need to check the validation of the form from outside of the component and everywhere you need that form you got the validation state.

Look at that example
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-10db0

here we has two components `App` and `Form`
`Form`: Here we handle all the fields and validations
`App`: Here we got the callback of the validation state and we are able to print a error message or disable the buttons